# Flask SQLAlchemy Order by Field

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have successfully ran a select statement in mysql as follows:

> SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY FIELD
>   (onlinecheck, 0, NULL, last_reboot) DESC, last_reboot DESC;

How do I run this same statement in Flask_SQLAlchemy?

BIG thanks to those who can assist :)

Answer (score 1):

So the best way I found to resolve this is by using a raw query method.

```
list = db.engine.execute('''SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY FIELD (onlinecheck, 0, NULL, last_reboot) DESC, last_reboot DESC;''').fetchall()
```

This resolves the issue. If someone has a better answer I'm all ears.